# Sql does not queue queries to linked server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, linked-server

i have a table in sql server and a table with the same name and fields in mysql server. i connected them trhough a linked server using the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER items_insert ON [prueba]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
declare @tmp table (a int, b varchar(10))
insert @tmp (a, b) select ID, Name from inserted
COMMIT
SET XACT_ABORT ON
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY(WEBDB, 'SELECT * FROM prueba')
SELECT a, b FROM @tmp
begin tran
end
```

my problem is that when i take offline the mysql serverm and i insert a record in sql server, it obviously does not insert in mysql, but when i put the mysql server it does not either. i want a queue of sorts, so that when the connection between servers drop, any new records during that time are inserted in mysql when the connection is restored. How could i achieve this?, i am new to sql server and triggers

NOTE: the trigger has the @tmp declarations according to [this](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/piotr_rodak/archive/2007/10/29/distributed-transactions-and-triggers.aspx) tutorial because i was getting a weird error about transactional errors

Comment: I would suggest to have a SQL Server job which runs on timely basis and picks up the records and pushes to the mysql database. You might need to keep track of what records were pushed using some boolean column in your SQL server table.

Answer (score 2):

Triggers will never queue and using linked servers inside a trigger is [a bad idea](http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/5431/linked-server-trigger-problem.html). You will find hundreds of people burning their fingers with this one I did too.

For any queue type system you will need to implement service broker or as Nilesh pointed out use a job which queue the tables.

Your current setup is going to be very problematic as I used the same approach several years ago in a attempt to get data from SQL2005 to a MySQL server. Incidental in SQL2000 you could actually replicate the data from MSSQL to any other ODBC datasource. Microsoft discontinued this in SQL2005.

So you have two choices here.

1. Learn Service Broker: Service broker is a awesome but little used piece of SQL. It is a asynchronous queuing technology that allows you to send message to other remote systems check [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx) link for much more information. However this is going to take time and effort to implement as you will have to learn quiet a bit i.e. steep learning curve.
2. Create a queue table and process on a schedule. Create a table that has the data you want to insert into MySQL with a processed flag. In the trigger insert this data into the table. Create a SQL server job that runs every minute and inserts the data from the queuing table into the MySQL database. On successful insertion mark it as processed.
3. Add a processed flag to the original table. Create a job that uses the table to get all items that have not been inserted and insert them on a schedule. This is like option 2 but you dont create a additional table.